# How to show branch merging after svn2git in gitk

Tags: git, gitk, svn2git

I used svn2git to migrate a svn project with branches.  The branches show up in gitk, but the graph does not show the branches merge back in.  Check in comments indicate where the merges happened.  Is there a way to manipulate the history such that the gitk graph shows the branches merging back into the master?

Comment: have a look at `git filter-branch --parent-filter`

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this as well while working on converting some projects to git. I found [this blog post](http://agavi.tumblr.com/post/16865375185/fixing-svn-merge-history-in-git-repositories) that helped me work out how to use a grafts file and then git filter-branch to rewrite the git history and make the changes permanent. It is a bit of manual work to find all the commit hashes and tie them together right but does achieve the desired results.